# Locally working with CNAMEs in multi-tenant apps

Tags: dns, multi-tenant, cname

I have a multi-tenant app where the user gets a subdomain `youraccount.myapp.com` that works fine. I have some customers who want to be able to have their own domain that redirects to the subdomain. So something like foobar.com --> youraccount.myapp.com. I'm pretty sure I've got the logic down in my app, but I have no idea how to test this on the DNS CNAME side of things. I don't want to launch this feature without seeing it work locally.

I feel like adding a host entry isn't going to test the logic, but maybe I'm wrong? Anyone know how to test this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have any other records together with a CNAME.

Since a "domain name", i.e. a "zone cut" where the parent zone contains NS records pointing to the delegated domain, *must* have an SOA record (and probably its own copies of the NS records, plus any other relevant and necessary records), it cannot also have a CNAME.

So the only way for the customer's own domain to point to the app subdomain would be for their domain name to also have an A record that points to the same address as the `youraccount.myapp.com` record points to.

The best they can do is to have their own subdomain that points to your subdomain, e.g. (using your example names):

```
app.foobar.com.  IN CNAME  youraccount.myapp.com.
```